# Can I mux H.265 into FLV by force?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, flv, h.265

We want to try **H.265** encoded video stream, but the video cloud server vendor we are using only provides **RTMP+FLV** uploading port. I have made some search works, and it seems **FLV** do not officially support **H.265** video stream. However the server vendor claim to support H.265, and asked us to modify codec ID to 12.

So I want to know that:

- What is codec ID? Is it an **FLV**-specific marker to identify various stream formats?
- Is it possible to unofficially support **H.265** being wrapped in **FLV**?
- We are using `ffmpeg` for streaming, is it possible to do that using `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is codec ID? Is it an FLV-specific marker to identify various stream formats?

Yes. Read the [FLV file specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/flv/pdfs/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf) for more info and see page 8 for the video data part of the bitstream format.

> Is it possible to unofficially support H.265 being wrapped in FLV?

Yes, but it's not defined by Adobe, hence, compatibility will suffer – the FLV format is not as extensible as ISOBMFF. It's also unlikely that with the death of Flash-based streaming and the surrounding technologies, H.265 support will be officially added. But I don't know much about Adobe's plans there.

> We are using ffmpeg for streaming, is it possible to do that using ffmpeg?

No. There was a [request to support HEVC/H.265 in FLV](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6389), with a somewhat spammy touch to it. Apparently the requirements for streaming (and CDN architectures) in China are somewhat different from what the rest of the industry is shifting to (HLS or DASH streaming over HTTP).
But the bottom line is that FFmpeg will not add support for custom, non-standardized extensions.

Comment: I remember that ticket. "Let's annoy the developers as much as we can by spamming the ticket." A prime example of how not to ask for a new feature.

Answer (score 0):

@jiandingzhe there are hardware encoders which will produce HEVC/h.265 in AMF format over RTMP. I'm the maintainer of Red5 and we accept their stream and with near-future work it'll be implemented in a commercial offering. I have  answers for two of your questions:

1. The codec id for h.265 that we and the hardware encoder use is 12 as seen here: HEVC((byte) 0x0c) at https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/blob/50a2c339ba027566c192b3bbf1c6714ca25df799/io/src/main/java/org/red5/codec/VideoCodec.java#L22
2. Yes, but a player would need to know how to play it back from the flv; I should have our reader and writer working within the next few weeks for Red5.

As stated I am the maintainer and its clearly in my profile. Project repo may be found here https://github.com/Red5/red5-server

Hardware encoders on Amazon: https://www.amazon.com/stores/ESZYM/page/BD2C2740-E01B-4312-8293-4DB83D948D51?ref_=ast_bln